# How does a distributed data clean room work?

Tags: multiparty-computation

I'm learning about the scheme of a distributed data clean room. It appears to be similar to an MPC (Multi-Party Computation) framework. What is the difference between them, and why does it run faster than a normal MPC?

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/distributed-data-clean-rooms-powered-by-snowflake/

Answer (score 1):

MPC is a topic of scientific study. "Distributed data clean room" is a meaningless marketing term, used only by this one company from what I can tell.

Their [whitepaper](https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/How-Snowflakes-Data-Clean-Rooms-Help-Publishers-and-Marketers-Improve-Ad-Effectiveness-040622.pdf) doesn't explain anything of substance. It says the data is encrypted (at rest), but never really makes any tangible statement about cryptographic security guarantees of the computation. I expect they're just using some trusted hardware enclave or something even less secure/sophisticated. Perhaps they mention Yao's protocol hoping that you'll read about them with fancy cryptography in mind.

Comment: Actually, I've encountered a few companies that use the term "data clean room", it seems to be widely spread among Ad companies (e.g. [Google](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/introducing-bigquery-data-clean-rooms?hl=en) uses it). It's indeed a marketing term, but after pressing one of these companies to explain more precisely what it refers to, it actually means Private Set Intersection (or slight generalizations thereof), which can be implemented through MPC or TEE.